# Many to many SQL

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I have an SQL which has **user**, **question** , and **answer** . I want to have a junction table which holds the rate of a question. Many users can rate many questions. Can you tell me what is wrong with this SQL? Here is the SQL :

```
 CREATE TABLE user
(
user_id int(4) NOT NULL,
user_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE question
(
question_id int(4) NOT NULL,
question_text longtext NOT NULL,
user_id int(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (question_id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE answer
(
answer_id int(4) NOT NULL,
user_id int(4)NOT NULL,
question_id int(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (answer_id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id),
FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES question (question_id)
);

CREATE TABLE rate
(
user_id int(4) REFERENCES user NOT NULL,
question_id int(4) REFERENCES question NOT NULL,
rate int(4) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: gives us also a guide for how you want them to be related, as I think you've got the concept wrong. i.e. A user should not be associated with a question IMO.

Answer (score 2):

In your rate table, you have to set up foreign keys on separate lines like you did in the other tables.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to syntax mistakes outlined by **Dan Bracuk**, I'd say some unique constraints are missed from the model.

I believe 1 user can answer 1 question only once, then `answer` should have unique key on (user_id, question_id). The same for `rate` , `user_id,question_id` should form unique constraint / PK .  Also, normally `username` is unique as well.

In case you want to allow the same user to answer or rank the same question or more than once , then date_time attribute is missed in `answer` and `rate` .